# jQuery plugin - autocomplete - adding tags as on Stackoverflow

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tags, stack-overflow

What jQuery autocomplete plugin can I use to add **several** tags as on Stackoverflow ? Can you also give me some examples of how it works ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the jQuery UI autocomplete widget? It allows you to select multiple options as shown here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be of help. For future reference, jQuery UI is a great library to turn to for things like this. Have a look through the widgets it provides, there's a lot of great functionality in there.

Comment: Which ones are your favorite ?

Comment: Well that completely depends on the situation! The ones I probably use most are autocomplete, dialog and tabs. If I had to pick a 'favorite', it would probably be the dialog - it's so much simpler to use than other lightbox scripts out there.